# Passing pointers to a function causes reading unaccessible address in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a program and in there, I dynamically allocate memory by using malloc; here is the important part:

```
unsigned int *hours;
unsigned int *minutes;
hours = (unsigned int *) malloc(n * sizeof(*hours));
minutes = (unsigned int *) malloc(n * sizeof(*minutes));
```

After this, I have a for loop, that loops n times; each time it reads time and stores hours at hours[i] and minutes at minutes[i];  `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

I read n before allocation using :

```
scanf(%d, &n);
```

Next, I have function, that takes 3 parameters, it looks like this:

```
void convertToMinutes(unsigned int *hours[],unsigned int *minutes[],int n)
{
     unsigned int i;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         *minutes[i] =*hours[i]*60 + *minutes[i];
     }
}
```

This is part that causes program to crash. I'm using Dr. Memory to see what happens, here is dump:

```
Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0x00000005-0x00000009 4 byte(s)
# 0 convertToMinutes    
# 1 main                
Note: @0:00:11.408 in thread 1740
Note: instruction: mov    (%eax) -> %ecx
```

As you can see, it tries to read address at 0x00000005, which causes Windows to shut it down.

So before calling this function, I looked at addresses of hours and minutes arrays and here is what I found:

```
for n = 3
hours base 10948584
hours+1    10948588
hours+2    19848592
minutes base 10948608
minutes+1    10948612
minutes+2    10948616
```

(Addresses are converted to int)

I'm lost. I have no idea what is wrong. Pointers are new to me (I've been using them for few days) and I have no idea why it suddenly tries to read at forbidden address.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You allocate a block of n ints, but then you treat it as if it's a block of n pointers to ints. `*minutes[i]` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function signature takes arguments that are arrays of `pointer` to unsigned int

```
void convertToMinutes(unsigned int *hours[],unsigned int *minutes[],int n)
```

but your arrays are arrays of `unsigned int` not `unsigned int *`. Try changing it to

```
 void convertToMinutes(unsigned int hours[],unsigned int minutes[],int n)
```

or (since array arguments will decay to a pointer anyway) even

```
void convertToMinutes(unsigned int* hours,unsigned int* minutes,int n)
```

The inside the function remove the dereferencing and change to:

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     minutes[i] = hours[i]*60 + minutes[i];
 }
```

Comment: He is using pointers not arrays, probably best to use the last example you give just to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you intend to use `hours` and `minutes` as integer arrays. In that case your allocation should be something like

```
hours = (unsigned int *) malloc(n * sizeof(hours));
```

But definitely this is not causing the crash. I think the problem is the way you are passing arguments to the function and accessing them.

Following might be what you want to do.

```
void convertToMinutes(unsigned int *hours,unsigned int *minutes,int n)
{
     unsigned int i;
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         *(minutes+i) =*(hours+i)*60 + *(minutes+i);
     }
}
```

For an array arr[4] will be equal to *(arr+4)
You can read up [here](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch2x.htm).